# Added Billing permission, Google Play not recognizing it in APK

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I created a new keystore and release key. Signed with both V1 + V2 persmissions.

Android manifest includes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="coffeechoices.quantumproductions.com.choicescoffee.test" >

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"></uses-permission>
```

Curiously, the `.BILLING`  phrase was not autocompletable. But that's what I saw on https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

I uploaded the APK, now Google Play says

"Your app doesn't have any in-app products yet. 
To add in-app products, you need to add the BILLING permission to your APK.
Upload a new APK"

Comment: Don't downvote just because there are similar questions. I looked at those and asked a valid question.

Comment: Did you resolve this? Did you add the in-app billing library?

Comment: There are 3 AndroidManifest.xml files. Are you sure you added this permission not only to the AndroidManifest.xml in the debug directory but also to the one in the profile directory? 
By the way, I am also having this problem. I wrote to Google Play support, I will share here if I receive any feedback.

Comment: This could possibly happen if you haven't released the app with billing permission across all tracks

Answer (score 2):

This should work, though the format

`<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />`

is recommended, rather than having open and close tags. I doubt that matters but you could try it.

To verify you really do have the permission you can try:
`aapt d permissions "MyApp.apk"` using the aapt tool which comes with the Android SDK. That will tell you if you have made a mistake.

If it doesn't work it is a bug and you should contact Google Play developer support using the "Contact us" link on the Question mark (Help) icon in the Play console.